# Модульные проекты на C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, модульность

Долгое время ищу информацию о создании модульного проекта на C++.

Т.е., чтобы реализовать следующее:

1) Создать ядро программы

2) Создать два модуля (например, nmHashCounter и xxHashCounter)

3) В зависимости от того, какой модуль заинклуден - выполнять действия в модуле, если заинклудены оба - вылетать в ошибку при компиляции.

4) Если же не один из модулей не заинклуден, то выполнять стандартные действия.

Например,

есть класс User с функцией DoSMTH, которая по умолчанию выдает надпись "You're Welcome!".

Мы инклудим DiabloModule, и теперь при вызове DoSMTH будет появляться "Welcome to HELL!".

Как это реализовать?

Есть ли идеи?

Спасибо, хорошего дня!

Comment: Что в вашем понимании модуль? Просто с одной стороны это вроде как .cpp-файлы, с другой - ваш, гм, термин "заинклуден" заставляет думать о заголовочных файлах. Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос так, чтоб его нельзя было трактовать иначе как правильно :) Решения есть, но надо понимать, решения **чего**...

Comment: @Harry я понимаю под модулем cpp + hpp

Comment: например  директивами препроцессора условной компиляции

Comment: Почему то мне кажется, что  под таким заголовком люди будут ожидать   другую информацию...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вам **простейший** вариант. Есть масса более хитрых, но зачем сложно, если можно просто? :)

**FIRST.HPP**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
inline void doIt(int)
{
    std::cout << "Hello First\n";
}
```

**SECOND.HPP**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
inline void doIt(int)
{
    std::cout << "Hello Second\n";
}
```

**MAIN.CPP**

```
#include <iostream>
//#include "first.hpp"
//#include "second.hpp"

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void doIt(T)
{
    cout << "Hello, World\n";
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    doIt(0);
}
```

Оставите как есть - выведет `Hello, World`.
Уберете комментарий с `#include "first.hpp"` - выведет `Hello First`.
Уберете комментарий с `#include "second.hpp"` - выведет `Hello Second`.

Уберете оба комментария - не скомпилируется.

Примерно то же самое можно для классов, других функций и т.п.

Варианты посложнее - например, когда каждый модуль регистрируется в основной программе - правда, проверка при этом уже на уровне выполнения. Но вполне можно добавить вот такие же одинаковые функции именно для единственности модуля.

И C++17 тут совершенно ни к чему. Это и C++03 умел - ведь `inline` я использовал, по сути, чтоб ограничиться .hpp-файлами  :)